# ASP.NET MVC web application access and modify database recurrently best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-webjobs

My applications users have a balance attribute that needs to be updated as long as they have services activated. So far, the update functionality uses a [.net webjob](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started/) that runs every hour (webjobs can run every hour at the most for shared or basic subscriptions).

Is there a better solution to implement a balance update feature? I also considered doing that on `Application_Start()` the following way:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    private PaymentsController paymentsController = new PaymentsController();

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Timer tmr = new Timer();
        tmr.Interval = 60000;   //1 minute
        tmr.Elapsed += updateUsersBalance;
        tmr.Start();
    }
    private void updateUsersBalance(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var users = db.Users.ToList();
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            user.balance -= 1;
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        db.SaveChanges();   //save updated balances
    }
```

Is this a reliable mechanism to update the balance every minute? Is it ok to have a reference to the database and a controller in the `Global.cs` file?
(leave aside the precision of the timer)

In my case this scenario would be preferable to a webjob because of the limitation that I can run them every hour at the most.

Comment: Actually, if you want to do this with WebJobs and not pay for the scheduler, you can easily do it with their newest feature. Here's a link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/extensible-triggers-and-binders-with-azure-webjobs-sdk-1-1-0-alpha1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this would not be a reliable method by itself.  It is possible for IIS to shut down the app pool and therefore your loop wouldn't be running. You could possible get around that by just setting up [ASP.NET Auto-Start](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series) (in Azure there is an "Always On" switch in the Configuration page to enable it) but really a job runner is probably the better option (in addition to ASP.NET Auto-Start).  Maybe checkout [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) (which is what we are currently using) or [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

Answer (score 1):

@nest I did not understand exactly what is your architecture, but I think that I understand what you need.

Getting your balance updated every minute is something virtual, think about it: "Why you need to update your balance if no one read it?"

With that in mind you can assert that your balance is updated whenever someone access it. This way you save processing resources. So you don`t need to bother about run this process on every minute, you need to run every time is has changes and for redundancy you can recalculate before the access.

That said you can use a Job Scheduler to calculate the balance, I suggest [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/), force the Job to run every time someone change values and also schedule to run on an interval or force to run if that interval is not met on someone access.

Of course this way you`ll need to change to Web Role, mainly because Hangfire has a web interface to you admin your jobs.

Comment: If a user goes to a negative balance we want to stop services for him and send notifications automatically. This is why it should be running all the time.

Comment: Sure, but you agree that if a user goes negative only when it has a transaction? It'll not be negative without a transaction.

You'll only need to do this schedule if an outside system register a transaction, this way you can use the Azure Scheduler (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) to call your balance method on a Web API endpoint.

Comment: It's not like that. If a user has a service enabled it keeps consuming. The only possible transaction is topping up. Consumption is continuous